Why are pronouns in gender-like listings always come in threes?
In a bio you might be asked to list the pronouns you'd like to be addressed with. For example:

they/them/theirs

or

she/her/hers

But why does this list has three entries? Wouldn't it be enough to indicate "she" only, and the "her" and the "hers" follows grammatically from it? And wouldn't apply the same logic to "he" (with "him" and "his") and "they" (with "them" and "theirs")?
Or asked the other way around: Are combinations like "he/her/theirs" in a modern gender-diverse grammar possible?

Anything is possible, but somebody stating the combination "he/her/theirs" should be less surprised when others make good-faith errors.

It seems quite common at least in the UK (and apparently Australia) just to give two pronouns e.g. "he/him", "she/her", although there's still potential redundancy there.

@StuartF "Redundancy" -- that's the perfect word here! Thanks. Might add it to the question.

Two listed forms is the most common number in my experience, not three. See also this related question.

This question is a duplicate of Why do people use all 3 components in their gender pronouns?, but it should not be closed as such, as the answers posted to the older one are not as directly to the point as the ones here (see Mitch's first comment below the older question).

Nowadays, most people use only a few possible triples of pronouns:

he him his,
she her hers,
they them theirs,

but when the idea that you should choose your own pronouns started, there were many more possibilities suggested, for example:

e em eirs,
tey tem ters,
zie zim zirs.

And for sets of pronouns like these, just saying zie isn't sufficient, as most people would not know the objective and possessive pronouns that correspond toe zie.
I believe that there are still some people who would like to go by unconventional pronouns like zie/zim/zirs.
See, for example, this webpage.

Great, very illuminating answer! Thank you!

You would ordinarily expect the objective and possessive pronouns to be the ones that are traditionally derived from the subjective pronoun, so listing all three seems redundant.
But one of the points of allowing people to choose their preferred pronouns is that they don't feel they fall into traditional norms. So for full flexibility and inclusivity, we allow people to choose each form individually, and there could be someone who prefers "she/them/his".

Makes sense. But if we want to give flexibilty taht doesn't mean that we can't have some _defaults. I suggest: "she" alone can be expanded to "she/her", can be expanded to "she/her/hers". No need to write it out - but I feel that the expectation of a tripled is still looming amongst us...

Also if you have something more unusual like "ze/hir/xe" it's good to spell it out in full.

@halloleo Perhaps, and maybe over time this will evolve into a more efficient format.

@Barmar I hope so. :-)

Are we actually "allowing people to choose their preferred pronouns," though? At a Pride fair booth last month I saw an array of pronoun T-shirts that seemed to limit the possibilities to "he/him," "she/her," and "they/them." Are people allowed to choose, say, a Buberesque "thou/thee" (subtext: if you're going to say something about me, say it to me), or perhaps "it/it," without risking cancellation on suspicion of mocking this whole pronoun business?

@BrianDonovan Good question. I'd like to think so, but I'm not in that community so I don't know for sure. It's also a very new thing so there's not much precedent.
